# Centering text in a trapezium div which uses unsorted list

Tags: html, css, menu

trying to get each trapezium to have text centered in them - but not sure how to!

http://jsfiddle.net/fYkq4/

HTML structure follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <ul><div class="fade-div" id="trapezium1"> HOME </div></ul>
    <ul><div class="fade-div" id="trapezium2"> HOME </div></ul>
    <ul><div class="fade-div" id="trapezium3"> HOME </div></ul>
    <ul><div class="fade-div" id="trapezium4"> HOME </div></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</ul>
```

I use the CSS border fidgeting technique to get the trapeziums, however as the shapes get inverted I have to change between using `border-bottom: 80px solid blue;` and `border-top: 80px solid blue;` - i.e. if I use **top** the text is below the trap, if i use **bottom** the text is inside (*but really below*) the trap.

How can I make it so all the `HOME`'s are consistently inside each trapezium? 
Do I need to move the text out of the div and make the divs float? Or put the text into another div and make it float?

Comment: Why do you have `div`s inside the `ul`s? Any particular reason why you're not following the rules?

Comment: No reason, willing to change the structure if needed. Just started out as using `ul`, then added the trapeziums `div`s randomly. Beginner web dev, not too sure about all the rules

Comment: An `ul` is a list. It should contain only list items, `li`elements. That's how they are designed; other uses are considered errors. And since different browsers respond differently to errors, I'd strongly suggest not using things for purposes they're not designed for. So play it safe and use only `div`s, not `ul`s in this example. Playint it safe will save you lots of headaches when trying your webpages on other browsers than the one you designed them on!

Comment: TL;DR change every `ul` to `div`.

Comment: Ah ok, I just thought initially, I would do the menu using just `ul`s (i.e. vertical rectangular menu) [a lot easier adding padding/margin to `ul`s], then add the trapezium `div`s for the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xonium/PqXbu/

Where the important part is the blocker

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="fade-div" id="trapezium1"> HOME1 </li>
      <li class="fade-div" id="trapezium2"> HOME2 </li>
      <li class="fade-div" id="trapezium3"> HOME3       
        <div class="blocker"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="fade-div" id="trapezium4"> HOME4 
        <div class="blocker"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

which acts as just like your upper two trapezium, just inverse colors.

```
.blocker {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 0;
  width:0;
  right:0;
  border-bottom: 80px solid red;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `line-height` equal to the height of the item you want it centered in.

So:

```
ul div {line-height:80px;}
```

Comment: This works but not fully, since I use `border-bottom` and `border-top` individually per each div some of them don't have text appearing consistently (*i.e. some appear inside the trapezium/border some appear below*)